# Series of task to be done after a single stroke in Easystroke gesture recognition

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, gestures

I use easystroke for many tasks like command, key combination, etc.
Now, I need to perform a series of tasks in a single stroke.

For example:

First i need to execute the command 'cryptkeeper'.

Second, I need to execute 'gnome-terminal'.

Third, I need to press key combination "ctrl+c".

Fourth, i need to press 'up-arrow'. Then 'Enter'

...

Here, i need to do step 1 to 4 with a single stroke in Easystroke.

Is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not sure if this will work, and I am can't test it now, but try it.

Install `xte`: `sudo apt-get install xautomation`

In easy-stroke make sure "Type" is set to "Command", then in the "Details" field put:

```
cryptkeeper && gnome-terminal && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown C' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup C' 'key Up' 'key Return'
```

In the end, it should look something like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response..Your answer helped me upto some extend. The code you provided will not work as in a single line..So, I added them to a shell script and invoked using a specified gesture. Thanks again for introducing me XTE.

Comment: @001neeraj Could you post an answer detailing what you did? This way other poeple can do it as well?  Thanks!

Comment: forgive me for the delay in reply. I've answered the way i did it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Where `secret.h` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cryptkeeper&
gnome-terminal -e "gnome-panel"&
xte 'sleep 5'
xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'
xte 'sleep 5'
gnome-terminal -e "gnome-panel"&
```

I am posting this because it may be useful to some others by editing the code. 'xdotool' can be used instead of xte.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Hmm, I think this is equivalent to replacing the following command line in Seth's answer: `cryptkeeper & gnome-terminal & xte 'sleep 5' ; xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L' ; xte 'sleep 5' ; gnome-terminal -e "gnome-panel" &` Note that `a && b` will start b when a has finished successfully, `a ; b` will start b when a has finished, `a & b` starts both simultaneously.